# Is it possible to have "sub-models" with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I was wondering if it was possible to have "sub-models" within Entity Framework entity models?

For example, this:

```cs
public class User
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public UserPermissions Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class UserPermissions
{
   public bool CanRead { get; set; }

   public bool CanWrite { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the actual table, there would be these columns:

```
Id
CanRead
CanWrite
```

or even with a prefix, like that:

```
Id
Perm_CanRead
Perm_CanWrite
```

Is that a thing? Is there an alternative you may know of? Or is my best bet to use a base/abstract class like `public class User : UserPermissions { }`?

Comment: What your expected result look like? What is the problem with your "best bet"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible in EF Core by using owned entities. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) explain it pretty well but, for example, you can have this:

```
[Owned]
public class StreetAddress
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public StreetAddress ShippingAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you prefer using the fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().OwnsOne(p => p.ShippingAddress);
```

Which will give you a table like this:

[image]

Comment: Learned something new

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot! Learned something new here as well (: